# non programmer--Read data from mySQL into bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I am not  programmer and I am very new to Highcharts.
Connection to the db works, the x,y axis of the chart and labels show up, but no data.
I got this entire script from the Highchart's forum [here][1].

Question: How to I get the graph to show the data from the columns 
graduation_year and i_am_a_student?

I'm sure to the folks here it's a no-brainer, but to me it's a brick wall!  TIA for any
help anyone can send my way.

this is the complete script.  I added the json bit as you suggested.

```
   <php
       $db = mysql_connect("localhost","un","pw","db");
   if ( $db == "" ) { echo " DB Connection error...\r\n"; exit(); }

   connects to db fine

   $sql = mysql_query($con,"SELECT graduation_year,i_am_a_student FROM wp_gfsept2013");
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
```

I think my problem is with the code below. I do not have the technical knowledge
to modify it to display the data from my table.  I've tried various things but no luck.

```
    $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $date    = strtotime($row['date']);
             $stamp    = $date * 1000;
             $val    = (int)$row['value'];

             $d[$i]['x'] = $stamp;
             $d[$i]['y'] = $val;
             $i++;
          }
   echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

   ?>

   <div id="container" style="width:800px;height:300px;margin:1em auto;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
               defaultSeriesType:'column',
               renderTo:'container'
            },
            credits:{enabled:false},
            title:{text:'Sample Chart'},
            legend:{
            },
            tooltip:{
            },
            plotOptions:{
               series:{
                  shadow:false,
                  borderWidth:0,
                  color:'rgba(90,155,212,.75)',
               }
            },
            xAxis:{
               title:{text:''},
               type:'datetime',
               lineWidth:1,
               lineColor:'#999',
               tickColor:'#999',
               tickLength:3,
            },
            yAxis:{
               lineWidth:1,
               lineColor:'#ccc',
               tickColor:'#999',
               tickLength:3,
               tickWidth:1,
               gridLineWidth:1,
               gridLineColor:'#e0e0e0',
               title:{text:''}
            },
            series:[{
          data: [<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>],
            }]
         });
      });
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts uses a number values, so I advice to set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag to return correct values. If it will not solve yor problem, please attach code which you use (not from source code from chrome) but you chart confgiuration / getting json etc.